# A question about conditional probability and independent random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability, exponential-distribution

I need some help with this following question:
Given two independent random variables $X\sim \exp(1),Y\sim \exp(1)$
$Z \sim X+Y$.
We want to calculate $f_{X|Z}(x,z)$.

So first I'd like to calculate $F_{X,Z}$

$$F_{X,Z}(x,z) = P(X\le x, Z\le z) = P(X\le x, X+Y\le z) = P(X\le x, Y\le z-X).$$

My question is, is it okay to say that:
$$P(X\le x, Y\le z-X) = P(X\le x)\cdot P(Y\le z-X),$$
because they are independent?

Comment: It is not OK. $Y \leq z-X$ involves $X$ and  it is not independent of $ (X \leq x)$.

Comment: Can you give me guidance on how to proceed from here?

Comment: Use the joint density of $(X,Y)$. You have to evaluate a double integral to get $P(X\leq x, Z\leq z)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $x\geq 0$. Using Total probability formula and the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are independents yields

\begin{align*}
\mathbb P\{X\leq x,Y+X\leq z\}&=\int_{\mathbb R}\boldsymbol 1_{\{s\leq x\}}\mathbb P\{Y\leq z-s\}f_X(s)\,\mathrm d s\\
&=\int_{0}^x \mathbb P\{Y\leq z-s\}f_X(s)\,\mathrm d s.
\end{align*}

Comment: I'll try that, thanks!